# Phonegap build plugin

Tags: cordova

I work on an phonegap build application and I want to put the [pushpugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/) to send notification to device ,but I don't know how to add a plugin.

In PhoneGap BUILD when I want to add a plugin must add the plugin(the java file,etc) or just add into config.xml and the build.phonegap will compile and add the plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of the documentation you linked to reveals that no further includes are required to use this plugin in you app.

So, just add the following to your config.xml, and then upload your files to build.phonegap.com:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />
```

The PhoneGap page for this plugin is:

[https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/)

Removing the suffix will bring you to the plugins page where you can search and filter core and  3rd party phonegap plugins:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/

Each plugin page gives an outline to what is needed to use it. I would recommend reading the documentation for each plugin as all are different.